# Conservation law relating magnetic geodesics and certain Killing fields

Tags: magnetic-fields, differential-geometry, conservation-laws, noethers-theorem

This is going to be somewhat math-heavy, but I'd like to make physical sense of this. Consider the following setup.

- $(Q, g)$ is a Riemannian manifold.
- $A \in \Omega^1(Q)$ is a magnetic potential ($1$-form).
- $X \in \mathfrak{X}(Q)$ is a Killing field such that $\mathcal{L}_XA = 0$.
- $B = {\rm d}A$ is the magnetic $2$-form.
- $F\colon TQ \to TQ$, characterized by $g_x(F_x(v),w) = B_x(v,w)$ for all $x \in Q$ and $v,w \in T_xQ$, is the Lorentz force.

Using Noether's theorem I have shown that if $\gamma\colon I \to Q$ is a magnetic geodesic, in the sense that $$\frac{{\rm D}\dot{\gamma}}{{\rm d}t}(t) = F_{\gamma(t)}(\dot{\gamma}(t))$$for all $t \in I$, then there is $c \in \Bbb R$ such that $$g_{\gamma(t)}(\dot{\gamma}(t), X_{\gamma(t)}) = A_{\gamma(t)}(X_{\gamma(t)}) + c$$for all $t \in I$.

This is a clear generalization of the fact that Killing fields satisfy that $t \mapsto g_{\gamma(t)}(\dot{\gamma}(t), X_{\gamma(t)})$ is constant if $\gamma$ is a geodesic of $(Q,g)$.

I would like to know if there's any interpretation for this conservation law or this constant $c$, now that magnetism enters into play. It seems that there should be a meaning since replacing $A$ with $A+{\rm d}f$ with $X(f)=0$, then $c$ is unchanged (this is some type of gauge invariance). I am not a physicist. Thank you!